# Django REST Framework Как вернуть список из обычного сериализатора?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Я пишу представление файловой системы на сервере. Для отображения дерева папок я использую [JSTree](https://www.jstree.com/). Для настройки AJAX подгрузки данных, необходимо вернуть JSON ответ определённого формата.

Для этого я создал следующее представление:

```
class MyFilesView(APIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]  # [IsAuthenticated]
    renderer_classes = [JSONRenderer, ]
    serializer_class = MyFilesSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        params = OrderedDict()
        params['query_params'] = request.query_params
        params['user_name'] = request.user.username
        serializer = self.serializer_class(params)
        _data = serializer.data
        return JsonResponse(data=_data, safe=False)
```

А также сериализатор, который должен посмотреть в папку сервера и сгенерировать JSON представление структуры папок на сервере:

```
class MyFilesSerializer(Serializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        results = []
        id = instance.get('query_params', {}).get('id','#')
        try:
            user_name = instance['user_name']
        except KeyError as e:
            raise ValueError(f'"user_name" parameter must be defined in "instance".\n Default message error: {str(e)}')

        tmp = {'id' : id if id else 'undefined', 'user_name' : user_name if user_name else 'undefined'}

        results.append(tmp)
        results.append(tmp)

        log_print(results)

        return results
```

Он ещё не дописан и, в рамках отладки, должен вернуть:

```
[
  {
    "id": "#",
    "user_name": "test_user"
  },
  {
    "id": "#",
    "user_name": "test_user"
  }
]
```

Но вместо этого он возвращает:

```
{
  "id": "user_name"
}
```

Я не знаю, как побороть это.
Представление вернёт нужный ответ, если скормить ему данные просто так, без сериализатора, но я хочу вынести логику генерации данных из представления.
Я знаю, что причина в том, что я пытаюсь вернуть список из обычного `Serializer`, вместо `ListSerializer`, но я не могу использовать `ListSerializer`, поскольку ему на вход нужно подать queryset, который будет равен количеству подпапок в текущей папке, а я этого не знаю, на момент вызова конструктора сериализатора.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вернуть список из обычного сериализатора.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю подойдет ли тебе такой вариант, но можно засунуть список в словарь:

`serializers`

```py
def to_representation(self, instance):
    results = [{"first": 1}, {"second": 2}]
    data = {
        "results": results,
    }
    return data
```

Добавляем во `views` - `data=_data['results']`

`views`

```py
return JsonResponse(data=_data['results'], safe=False)
```

Вывод:

```json
[
    {
        "first": 1
    },
    {
        "second": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Не поможет, к сожалению, JSTree ожидает другой формат. Я временно прописываю всю логику в представлении в качестве обходного решения, но хотелось бы переписать порядочным способом.

Comment: могу ошибаться, но во `view` же можно добавить вывод этого списка  `return JsonResponse(data=_data['results'], safe=False)`

Comment: Точно, спасибо. С этим комментарием я должен отметить это как ответ, подожду выходные, если не будет лучшего ответа, отмечу этот.

Comment: Не за что, хорошего дня!